# Is it bad practice to create a final static object list at compile time in Java?

Tags: java, list, compilation

I have a shared resource yaml file that I will be using for different language libraries.
The only purpose for these libraries at the moment is to get the values in that yaml file.

Is it more efficient to create a final static object list at compile time or would that just be bad practice?

My approach generates something like this:

```
private static final List<Person> persons = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Bob", new Address("Earth")),
        new Person("Dan", new Address("Mars"))
    ));

public static getPersons(){
    return this.persons;
}
```

Comment: Creating static final objects is often fine, but making it so you have to recompile your entire project to adjust some data is often undesirable.

Comment: What's the problem with just using the yaml file?

Comment: @LouisWasserman this will be a versioned library where each change in the yaml file will cause a version bump.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I thought it could be more efficient to create the class and list at compile time rather than reading the yaml file every time it is needed but was unsure on good/bad practices.

Comment: You can read the yaml file just once when your application starts up, and cache what's in it.  Or read it regularly, if it's likely to change while your application is running.  That might take milliseconds.

Comment: I would focus on what’s most efficient as a development workflow over micro-optimizing startup time.